# Accessing geocoder gem scopes

Tags: rails-geocoder

[The gem manual](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#for-activerecord-models) indicates `Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 20, :units => :km)`

However this application's model objects have two geocoded co-ordinates variables in addition to the individual longitudes and latitudes.  In order to test the various search options (postGIS, numerical indexes of lon and lat, or calling geocoder services) is there any way to access a specific model variable in the finding of objects near a given location?

The relevant schema data is:

```
t.decimal  "origin_lon",          precision: 15, scale: 10
t.decimal  "origin_lat",          precision: 15, scale: 10
t.spatial  "origin_lonlat",      limit: {:srid=>3857, :type=>"point"}
add_index "strappos", ["origin_lat"], :name => "index_strappos_on_origin_lat"
add_index "strappos", ["origin_lon"], :name => "index_strappos_on_origin_lon"
add_index "strappos", ["origin_lonlat"], :name => "index_strappos_on_origin_lonlat", :spatial => true
```

Comment: Show us the object's schema/model so we know exactly what it looks like

Comment: updated a while back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoCoder defaults to using `latitude` and `longitude` as their variable names. Since yours are different, you'll need to add an extra option in order to query `origin_lon` and `origin_lat`.

In your model, where you initialize `geocoder` for the model, you have the option of assigning a different name for the lat/lon attribute:

```
# YourModel.rb
geocoded_by :address,
  latitude: :origin_lat, 
  longitude: :origin_lon
```

I placed it on multiple lines for clarity. As you can see, I'm telling `geocoder` that my lat/lon attribute names are different than the defaults.

Now, querying the model using `near` will look at those new attribute names as opposed to the defaults.